# It's possible to create two topics with exactly the same name

Tags: bug, documentation

It is possible to have two documentation topics under the same tag with exactly the same name.

This is a problem because, among other things, it's impossible to choose which topic you want when two suggestions appear in the search box with the same name.

There should probably be something that prevents an edit from being submitted, or a topic from being created, where the title is exactly the same as some other topic's title.